# Laravel join with distinct

Tags: laravel, join

Hi all i have an issue to query two tables images and status wich contain comments for the images here the code i wrote

```
$images =  DB::table('statuses')
->join('images', 'images.user_id', '=', 'statuses.user_id')
->where(function($query){
return $query->where('statuses.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->orWhereIn('statuses.user_id', Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id'))
->where('statuses.parent_id', '=', 'images.id');
})->distinct()
->where('statuses.statusType', '=', '2')
->groupby('statuses.body')
->select('images.*','statuses.*')->orderBy('statuses.created_at', 'desc')
->get();
```

Here i explain: i'm getting a good result already :
[results from this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Pcl.png)

'aaaa' and 'bbbb' are tow comments to a photo all i need now is group those comments to get the same image with diffrent body.